# Where can I find Joomla usage statistics?

Tags: cms, joomla-framework-1.x, statistics

I'm interested in accessing accurate Joomla statistics such as the number of sites currently using Joomla cms and/or the Joomla framework.

Does anyone know where I can find this type of information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the only resource I could find that had report that are updated daily:

http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/cm-joomla/all/all

It also shows the percentages of different versions used too which comes in handy. Unfortunately this only refers to the CMS, not the framework.

All other resources I found are blog posts that are over a year old and as everyone knows, a lot can change in a year(+).

Hope this helps

Comment: That link has some pretty interesting information. I was gonna ask if you knew how they got their data, but I found the answer already at http://w3techs.com/technologies Thanks!

Comment: Be sure to look at their disclaimer too. There is some information in there that you might also want to take into consideration: http://w3techs.com/disclaimer

Comment: There's also: http://trends.builtwith.com/cms

Comment: @NeilRobertson - Good find. Please post as an answer ;)

Comment: @NeilRobertson - Likewise....+1 to you too

Answer (score 8):

There are also these:

- http://trends.builtwith.com/cms
- http://trends.builtwith.com/cms/Joomla!

The change in market share is considerable when the results are filtered to the top 1 million, top 100k and top 10k websites, especially with Drupal.

Given that a free WordPress website can be created in seconds, and this is not something that can currently be done with Joomla or Drupal, I suspect many of the counted WordPress websites are abandoned and that this skews the statistics unfairly in favour of WordPress.

**Jan 2015 Update:**

I just discovered datanyze.com which shows (for example) installed CMS usage at: https://www.datanyze.com/market-share/wcms

Datanyze also tracks wordpress.org and wordpress.com separately which is quite revealing compared to counting these as just "WordPress".

**March 2016 Update:**

With the release of Joomla 3.5.0, website owners can opt to contribute usage statistics centrally. These are available at https://developer.joomla.org/about/stats.html and there is also a public API at https://developer.joomla.org/about/stats/api.html.

Remember that this will only provide information about Joomla installs since the release of Joomla 3.5.0 as the feature is not included in earlier versions and obviously won't be counting the websites where the owners opted out of the option.

**September 2019 Update:**

I just discovered similartech.com which shows various Joomla statistics at: https://www.similartech.com/technologies/joomla

Comment: Your last link isn't working out, but the data visualization in the first link is great!

Comment: @NeilRobertson I am not sure if datanyze has pivoted since Jan 2015 but now it looks like a browser extension or a paid product service so I dont see that data at first look

Comment: Thanks @tristanbailey - I think they are pushing their browser extension product fairly heavily but some data is still available for free. I have added the direct link to the example in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You have to be careful with any of the reported data below and see it as data relative to that source data. No web service knows exactly the make up of the internet by cms or any technology as all the services crawl or sample the content base on meta tags or ways sites report in their code.

Some people remove these and some sites are put up and then left.

So talk to Jessica Dunbar the marketing for joomla, this was the JaB video I was at where she talks stats https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwttFiH2pbs